# JS Function to hide and show password doesn't work

Tags: javascript, passwords

Whi my function to hide and show my password does not work? Anyone could help me?

#HTML:

```
<div class="senha">
<i class="bi bi-key"></i>
<input type="password" required autofocus placeholder="senha" id="idsenha">
<i class="bi bi-eye"></i>
</div>
```

JS:

```
let btn = document.querySelector('.bi-eye');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

    let input = document.querySelector('#idsenha');

    if(input.getAttribute('type') == 'password') {
        input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    } else {
        input.setAttribute('type', 'password');
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens when you run it? Is there an error in your console?

Comment: Perhaps you're still seeing the placeholder text, which isn't affect by the type.

Comment: It simply does not show the password. It is strange, because down here(on the 'run code snippet') it shows it correctly.

Comment: Does the function even run? What happens when you log something in the function? If the JS is run before the DOM is loaded, it won't find `.bi-eye`.

Comment: GOD! I placed the JS in the HEAD instead in the END of Body! How dumb I am.! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you keep javascript inside the body tag, maybe your javascript code is not even running

Answer (score 2):

Your code works.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.bi-eye');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

  let input = document.querySelector('#idsenha');

  if (input.getAttribute('type') == 'password') {
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  } else {
    input.setAttribute('type', 'password');
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.2.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
<div class="senha">
  <i class="bi bi-key"></i>
  <input type="password" required autofocus placeholder="senha" id="idsenha">
  <i class="bi bi-eye"></i>
</div>
```